# When using df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna() Question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set filled with invoices columns including:

- CaseID
- Customer
- Supplier
- Part Number
- Cost.

This data set includes Charges and Credits. I want to remove the Credits and the Charges they credited from DataFrame. I'd like to remove the rows in original that are credits and the charges they pertain to. But there are some instances where a transaction was charged twice on accident so the information is a duplicate. I do not want to remove the duplicate if there is a credit since the duplicate will need a credit as well.

I have the original df.
I created a charge df where it is all rows with Cost > 0 from the original.
I created a credit df where it is all rows with Cost < 0 from the original.

My question is if I use `df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()` or in this case:

```py
invoiced[~invoiced.isin(credits)].dropna()
```

How do I specify that I only want the row dropped one time? Is it possible?

```
ex:
invoice = 

Case| Part_Number | Cost

111 | 2G | 53.00

112 | 7G | 25.00

112 | 7G | 25.00

113 | 8G | 20.00

113 | 8G | -20.00

114 | 9G | 15.00

115 | 2G | 53.00

115 | 2G | 53.00

115 | 2G | -53.00
```

```
Charge = 

Case| Part_Number | Cost

111 | 2G | 53.00

112 | 7G | 25.00

112 | 7G | 25.00

113 | 8G | 20.00

114 | 9G | 15.00

115 | 2G | 53.00

115 | 2G | 53.00
```

```
Credits =

Case| Part_Number | Cost

113 | 8G | -20.00

115 | 2G | -53.00
```

```
Output = 
df =

Case| Part_Number | Cost

111 | 2G | 53.00

112 | 7G | 25.00

112 | 7G | 25.00

114 | 9G | 15.00

115 | 2G | 53.00
```

See how it removed 113 since there was 1 charge and 1 credit but kept (1) of 115 since there were 2 charges and 1 credit.

Comment: I cant see the edit

Comment: Just to be clear, is the output you show above what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @JoeyMiths Yeah my data is different values but essentially yes. 
There are rows for each part on an invoice transaction.
I am looking for duplicate charges that have not been credited yet.

Comment: @JoeyMiths 
My original code did not include credits and I successfully identified all cases that had duplicate case, part, and cost. I would like to update it so that If case has a credit I do not want it to show on output. But some cases have 3+ of the same charge where the row is identical. I do not want to drop all rows just based on if there is an idenital case,part credit. i.e 1 charge 1 credit nothing on output for that case. 2 Charges 1 Credit, show 1 charge still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
invoices = pd.DataFrame([['111', '2g', 53],
                         ['112', '7g', 25],
                         ['112', '7g', 25],
                         ['113', '8g', 20],
                         ['113', '8g', -20],
                         ['114', '9g', 15],
                         ['115', '2g', 53],
                         ['115', '2g', 53],
                         ['115', '2g', -53]],
                        columns=['Case', 'PartNo', 'Cost'])

print(f"Original invoices:\n{invoices}\n\n")

newInvoices = invoices.copy()
newInvoices['Charge_Credit'] = 0

for idx, case, part, cost, ch_cr in newInvoices.itertuples():
    creditedDf = newInvoices[(newInvoices.Case == case) &
                          (newInvoices.PartNo == part) &
                          (newInvoices.Cost == -cost) &
                          (newInvoices.Charge_Credit != 'remove')]
    if len(creditedDf):
        newInvoices.loc[creditedDf.iloc[0].name,  'Charge_Credit'] = 'remove'

newInvoices = newInvoices[['Case', 'PartNo', 'Cost']][newInvoices.Charge_Credit != 'remove']
newInvoices.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(f"New invoices:\n{newInvoices}\n")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! I'm fairly certain this is exactly what was needed.  I started with 63,964 rows, 47,403 charges, and 16,561 Credits. So I expected to be around ~35k rows on the output depending if the credits were applied to charges in my date range. I am at 38k rows now. Thank again, much appreciated! Unfortunately I do not have the reputation to upvote your answer but this defintely seems exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, outputdf is supposed to show which invoice hasn't been paid yet, even if it is a duplicate, correct? I believe this is the code you're looking for and ill explain it in a bit.

```
dfinvoice = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Case', 'PartNo', 'Cost'],
                  data=np.array([['111', '2g', 53],
                                 ['112', '7g', 25],
                                 ['112', '7g', 25],
                                 ['113', '8g', 20],
                                 ['113', '8g', -20],
                                 ['114', '9g', 15],
                                 ['115', '2g', 53],
                                 ['115', '2g', 53],
                                 ['115', '2g', -53]
                                 ]))

dfcharge = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Case', 'PartNo', 'Cost'],
                  data=np.array([['111', '2g', 53],
                                 ['112', '7g', 25],
                                 ['112', '7g', 25],
                                 ['113', '8g', 20],
                                 ['114', '9g', 15],
                                 ['115', '2g', 53],
                                 ['115', '2g', 53]
                                 ]))

dfcredits = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Case', 'PartNo', 'Cost'],
                  data=np.array([['113', '8g', -20],
                                 ['115', '2g', -53]
                                 ]))
dfowing = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Case', 'PartNo', 'Cost'],
                  data= np.array([['111', '2g', 53],
                                  ['112', '7g', 25],
                                  ['112', '7g', 25],
                                  ['114', '9g', 15],
                                  ['115', '2g', 53]
                                  ]))
df = dfinvoice
for x, y in df.iterrows():
    for a, b in df.iterrows():
        if y[0] == b[0]:
            if x != a:
                first = int(y[2])
                second = int(b[2])
                if first > 0 and second < 0:
                    print(x, y)
                    print('compared to')
                    print(a, b)
                    df = df.drop(x)
                    df = df.drop(a)
print(df)
```

dfowing is what the dataframe should look like. I was using that as a reference.

Using a for loop in a for loop you can cross reference you're values. x and a being the index, y and b are the rows of data. in the first if statement I was checking if the invoice numbers matched. in the second if statement I had to make sure that the index didn't match so it would compare itself to the next row, although not exactly necessary. first and last are the the values from the 'cost' column which in my dataframe they were returning as a string and you cant compare integers and strings to check if one is greater or less than 0. in the last if statement check if one is greater than 0 and one is less than 0 and remove that row using the index using `df = df.drop()` to get rid of each match where an invoice has been charged and then credited.

I'm not the greatest at explaining these things so if anyone wants to edit my explanation feel free :)

Comment: This does seem to be what I am pretty much looking for. I started the code and it populated a few of the  prints but then I got an error stating '[0] not found in axis'. I am also using 65000 rows so is it okay to remove the (3) prints to save time and space?

Comment: There are 63,964 rows, 47,403 charges, and 16,561 Credits. My final output should be about 32,000 rows if all the credits apply to charges in my date range.

Comment: yeah its fine to remove the prints, not sure why it would throw an error with [0]. unless the first column isnt always populated. could you copy the full error so i can see which line is causing the issue